# Hibernate persist missing some record when large set of record are inserted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

We have scenarios where we need to insert record to a table when we are inserting record using `em.persist`  it gives us id which we are logging but some time ( 2K record out of 200K record ) the id which is logged is not present in DB.

When the insertion is going on (mentioned previously), another thread may insert record in the same table.

We are using EJB and injecting

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ecm-nocache")
 private EntityManager em;
```

Both the insertion is happening in different bean and triggered from Web services.

Note:  200K record insertion is happening from web services one by one

Since this is in production and we don't huge data set in test environment so unable to replicate same, how do I identify what is the issue, any lead would be appriciated

Thanks, A lot

```
ProductClassification pc = new ProductClassification();
 pc.setClassification(classification);
 pc.setProduct(product);
 em.persist(pc); 
 log.info( pc.getId()+"----"+classification.getId()+"----"+product.getId() );
```

Comment: 1. Do you get any exceptions? 2. How is the ID generated. 3. Where are the transaction boundaries?

Comment: I don't see any exceptions... It's ejb once call method is executed transactions is completed.... Id is autogenerated